# ¿hay alguna forma de "minimizar" la cantidad de eventos creados en javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, botón, dom

Soy nuevo en javascript, mi pregunta es la siguiente.
Ahora estoy aprendiendo json (fetch) y los items lo voy a generar ahi y los voy a imprimir desde JS. No sé la cantidad de elementos que voy a agregar... **¿existe alguna forma de agregar "automaticamente" desde javascript los eventos de los botones?**
espero que se entienda mi pregunta. dejo un ejemplo de cómo vengo agregando los eventos uno por uno.

````
const boton1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    agregarVentas(art1);
    mostrarCarrito();
})
const boton2 = document.querySelector("#boton2");
boton2.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    agregarVentas(art2);
    mostrarCarrito();
})
const boton3 = document.querySelector("#boton3");
boton3.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    agregarVentas(art3);
    mostrarCarrito();
})
const boton4 = document.querySelector("#boton4");
boton4.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    agregarVentas(art4);
    mostrarCarrito();
})
const boton5 = document.querySelector("#boton5");
boton5.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    agregarVentas(art5);
    mostrarCarrito();
})```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A todos los elemetos que compartan algo, les podemos poner la misma clase, eso sirve para los estilos y también para la funcionalidad. Si a todos los botones le pones la misma clase puedes seleccionarlos todos al mismo tiempo y asignarle la misma función, algo asi:

```js
const unaFuncion = (i) => {
  console.log(i)
};

[...document.getElementsByClassName("botones")].forEach(b => {

  b.addEventListener("click", () => { // <-- b es cada elemento de la clase "botones"
    unaFuncion(b.id); // <-- b.id es solo un ejemplo
  })

});
```

```html
<button id="boton1" class="botones">uno</button>
<button id="boton2" class="botones">dos</button>
<button id="boton3" class="botones">tres</button>
```

Así evitas hacer un `addEventListener` por cada botón.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias :)